# Displaying image from base64 encoded string

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I need to display an image in an image tag.

I use a simple XMLHttpRequest which returns the image data in an arrayBuffer.  The response data is sent to the following function to base64 encode it:

```
var base64EncodedImage = arrayBufferToBase64(response);

arrayBufferToBase64 = function(buffer) {
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
  }
 return window.btoa(binary);
}
```

Then I assign it to the src attribute on my image tag:

```
this.imageTag.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64EncodedImage;
```

...and no image appears.  I have tried using a bunch of different online encoders on the binary data and just copy pasting the result into the code (in case it's the window.btoa function that's messing things up) but no luck there either.

Am I making a stupid mistake (or missing a step) or does this look like it should work?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with real data you are trying?

Comment: Can you post one of the B64 image strings you are using?

Comment: If you use the same code to assign an normal image url to the img element, does it work?

Comment: here is the worlds simplest fiddle (just to give you some base64 data...

https://jsfiddle.net/abc7s6j7/

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed that something strange happens to the base64 encoded data after assigning it the source attribute.  If I examine the src attribute directly after assigning the response form the arrayBufferToBase64 function, there is some characters missing. Bizarre.

Comment: yes, codebox 20, that works fine.  Something odd with base64 data I think.

Comment: @SimpleSimon Your Base64 string is not a valid one. I substituted your string with a different one and the jsfiddle worked. I Tried to decode the string with different base64 online decoders and all returned a wrong data error

Comment: @Eineki That's what I suspected.  Using http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ tells me there are invalid characters (or more than 2 padding characters) but I don't know how to find the error!

Comment: @SimpleSimon There is a … char at 5025 pos in your string. For sure it is not a valid base64 char. You should investigate on his origin (a copy & paste after text expansion?)